# Как создать платёж и проверить его статус?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord, disnake

Как мне реализовать создание платежа и проверить его статус на клиенте (я пытаюсь прикрепить к боту discord (Python disnake))? Я пытался сделать это с помощью chatGPT, но безрезультатно, сервер возвращает ошибку 400 при попытке создания. Я прочитал документацию, написано, что можно посмотреть тело ответа, но возникла другая проблема, как посмотреть это тело, если оно выводит только код ошибки, который практически не дает никакой информации. Библиотека yookassa v3. Смотрел [документацию](https://yookassa.ru/developers/api#create_payment) и [примеры](https://git.yoomoney.ru/projects/SDK/repos/yookassa-sdk-python/browse/docs/examples/01-configuration.md) от самой юкассы, но особо не помогло. Да, я новичок

Мой код:

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import uuid
import var_dump as var_dump
from ids_list import admin
from yookassa import Payment, Configuration, Settings
from yookassa.domain.models.currency import Currency
from yookassa.domain.models.receipt import Receipt, ReceiptItem
from yookassa.domain.common.confirmation_type import ConfirmationType
from yookassa.domain.request.payment_request_builder import PaymentRequestBuilder
import json


Configuration.account_id = 'my super id'
Configuration.secret_key = 'super secret pay'


me = Settings.get_account_settings()
var_dump.var_dump(me)

class ls(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author == self.bot.user:
            return
        
        if isinstance(message.channel, disnake.DMChannel):
            if message.content == '2':
                if message.author.id == admin:
                        embed_1 = disnake.Embed(title="тест1")
                        await message.channel.send(embed=embed_1, components=[
                            disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.success, label="Создать платёж", custom_id="create_payment"),
                            disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.danger, label="Отмена", custom_id="cancel"),
                            ],
                        )
                else:
                    embed = disnake.Embed(
                        title = "тест2",
                        description = "текст2",
                        colour = 0xFFD966)
                    embed.set_thumbnail(url=url_icon)
                    embed.set_image(url=url_image)
                    await message.channel.send(embed=embed)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_button_click(self, interaction: disnake.MessageInteraction):
        if interaction.component.custom_id == "create_payment":
            with open('types.json') as f:
                types = json.load(f)
                payment = Payment.create({
                    "amount": {
                        "value": types['1']['amount']['value'],
                        "currency": types['1']['amount']['currency']
                    },
                    "confirmation": {
                        "type": "redirect",
                        "return_url": "https://google.com/"
                    },
                    "description": types['1']['description'],
                    "capture": true
                }, uuid.uuid4())
                var_dump.var_dump(payment)
                print(payment.content.decode())
                # payment_url = payment.confirmation.confirmation_url
                
            embed_2 = disnake.Embed(title="Payment create!", description=f"Ссылка на оплату: {payment.confirmation.confirmation_url}", colour=0x6AA84F)
            await interaction.message.edit(embed=embed_2, components=[
                disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.success, label="Проверить статус платежа", custom_id="check_payment"),
                disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.danger, label="Отменить", custom_id="cancel_payment"),
                ])
            payment_id = request.data['id']
            idempotence_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
            response = Payment.capture(
            payment_id,
            {
                "amount": {
                "value": types['1']['amount']['value'],
                "currency": types['1']['amount']['currency']
                }
            },
            idempotence_key
                )

        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "check_payment":

            res = Payment.find_one(self.payment.id)
            var_dump.var_dump(res)

            if res.status == 'succeeded':
                embed_3 = disnake.Embed(title="Поздравляю с покупкой")
                await interaction.message.edit(content="найс", embed=embed_3)
        
        elif interaction.component.custom_id == "cancel_payment":
            idempotence_key = str(uuid.uuid4())
            response = Payment.cancel(
            self.payment_id,
            idempotence_key
            )
            await interaction.message.edit(content="Платёж отменён")
```

Ошибка:

```
Ignoring exception in on_button_click
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\disnake\client.py", line 703, in _run_event        
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\pek\modules\ls.py", line 171, in on_button_click
    payment = Payment.create({
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\yookassa\payment.py", line 58, in create
    response = instance.client.request(HttpVerb.POST, path, None, headers, params_object)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 38, in request
    raw_response = self.execute(body, method, path, query_params, request_headers)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 59, in execute
    self.log_response(raw_response.content, self.get_response_info(raw_response), raw_response.headers)
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\yookassa\client.py", line 119, in get_response_info
    "raise_for_status": response.raise_for_status(),
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\L1te\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:  for url: https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments
```

Comment: Апикей у вас юрлицовый?

Comment: обычный апи ключ магазина